# Dynamically Generate TVP from an existing table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there is a way to generate a TVP from an existing table? I have tried this, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12596/using-tables-as-table-valued-parameters-tvp but it's showing me syntax error?

```
-- you would pass these two in as parameters of course:
DECLARE
  @TableName SYSNAME = N'LocationTable',
  @TypeName  SYSNAME = N'LocationTypeTable';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(9) 
    + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' '
    + s.name + CASE WHEN LOWER(s.name) LIKE '%char' THEN 
        '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), (c.max_length/
        (CASE LOWER(LEFT(s.name, 1)) WHEN N'n' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)) + ')' 
        ELSE '' END
        -- need much more conditionals here for other data types
    FROM sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN sys.types AS s
    ON c.system_type_id = s.system_type_id
    AND c.user_type_id = s.user_type_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName);

SELECT @sql = N'CREATE TYPE ' + @TypeName
    + ' AS TABLE ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + (' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, '')
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ');';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made modifications to your code above.  This code executes but returns no values.  What are you looking for exactly.

```
-- you would pass these two in as parameters of course:
DECLARE
  @TableName SYSNAME 
  Set @TableName = N'LocationTable'
DECLARE  
  @TypeName  SYSNAME 
  Set @TypeName =  N'LocationTypeTable'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) 
SET @sql= N'';

SELECT @sql = N',' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(9) 
    + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' '
    + s.name + CASE WHEN LOWER(s.name) LIKE '%char' THEN 
      --  '(' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), (c.max_length/
        (CASE LOWER(LEFT(s.name, 1)) WHEN N'n' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END))) 
       -- + ')' 
        ELSE '' END
        -- need much more conditionals here for other data types
    FROM sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN sys.types AS s
    ON c.system_type_id = s.system_type_id
    AND c.user_type_id = s.user_type_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@TableName);



SELECT @sql = N'CREATE TYPE ' + @TypeName
    + ' AS TABLE ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '(' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, '')
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ');';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I just realized from your link they are using adventureworks.  I don't have that installed.  Run this code against the adventureworks database.  Also the changes I made were things like missing single quotes and using set to assign a value to variables.

Comment: Please read the question carefully, I need to grab the syntex of TVP from an existing table

Comment: You said the code above was throwing an error.  I made the corrections to the code for you.  You did not give any names of tables, parameters you are trying to retrieve.  So, sorry I could not read your mind.